# Highcharts is not working using visual studio 2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, highcharts

```js
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    ['v11.0', 24.13],
                    ['v8.0', 17.2],
                    ['v9.0', 8.11],
                    ['v10.0', 5.33],
                    ['v6.0', 1.06],
                    ['v7.0', 0.5]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    ['v40.0', 5],
                    ['v41.0', 4.32],
                    ['v42.0', 3.68],
                    ['v39.0', 2.96],
                    ['v36.0', 2.53],
                    ['v43.0', 1.45],
                    ['v31.0', 1.24],
                    ['v35.0', 0.85],
                    ['v38.0', 0.6],
                    ['v32.0', 0.55],
                    ['v37.0', 0.38],
                    ['v33.0', 0.19],
                    ['v34.0', 0.14],
                    ['v30.0', 0.14]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    ['v35', 2.76],
                    ['v36', 2.32],
                    ['v37', 2.31],
                    ['v34', 1.27],
                    ['v38', 1.02],
                    ['v31', 0.33],
                    ['v33', 0.22],
                    ['v32', 0.15]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    ['v8.0', 2.56],
                    ['v7.1', 0.77],
                    ['v5.1', 0.42],
                    ['v5.0', 0.3],
                    ['v6.1', 0.29],
                    ['v7.0', 0.26],
                    ['v6.2', 0.17]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    ['v12.x', 0.34],
                    ['v28', 0.24],
                    ['v27', 0.17],
                    ['v29', 0.16]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        $ {
            demo.css
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 
</body>
 </html>
```

I want a pie with drill down effect.
I found this snippet in the highcharts plugin. While I am loading this code with normal html file, it is working fine. But while implementing this in the ASP.NET web form it is showing the first pie without drill down.
What may be the problem?
I am using Visual studio 2010.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: JavaScript Console is attached and accepting commands.

Comment: I got this warning in the console, except this no errors.

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You did not attached the code how you tried to implement that chart.

Comment: Line: 10
Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14   why i am getting this error.

Comment: Line: 10
Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14